# 'CGAffineTransform' is not convertible to 'ConstUnsafePointer<CGAffineTransform>'

Tags: ios, swift, cgpath

I get the error message in the title when using this:

```
CGPathContainsPoint(Hitbox.CGPath, self.transform, point, false)
```

Hitbox is a `UIBezierPath`, self is a `UIView` and point is a `CGPoint`.

I have absolutely no idea what to search for or what this error is, please dont be too harsh. How should I correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function takes a pointer to a `CGAffineTransform` struct, rather than a struct value. So you need to do something like this:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = self.transform;
CGPathContainsPoint(Hitbox.CGPath, &transform, point, false)
```